# What happens with an image file, when I store it in a database?

Tags: image, binary, blob, sqldatatypes

Went through many articles in the internet talking about how to store images in the database. But unfortunately none of them explain what exactly happens with the data itself when is store in a db.

Most of the articles show that the data is stored in a binary, image or blob data type field, and just checking an application here, instead of binary information, I have what seems to be a memory address, something like 0x123445323403923... and so on.

1.Is it the address where the actual binary data is stored?

2.If so, how is this binary "recompiled" into a TIF or JPEG when its retrieved from the db?

So I was wondering if someone could provide an explanation about what happens in the sense described above.

Thank you for your answers and information in advance.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

What you see in database is not memory addresses but actual bytes in hexadecimal representation, as indicated by the `0x` prefix. An image file, like any other file, is a collection of bytes. When it is saved as binary, it is the plain (or raw) bytes which are saved. A common way to represent raw bytes is using hexadecimal representation. In hexadecimal, each byte is represented by two characters from the character set `0123456789abcdef` or `0123456789ABCDEF`. If you view the image file using hex file viewer like [HxD](http://download.cnet.com/HxD-Hex-Editor/3000-2352_4-10891068.html) you should see same values as the ones starting with `0x` in database.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit broad but in general:

A database stores and retrieves data and as such will not usually have knowledge about complicated types (images, sounds, animations, electronics schematics etc.) , it deals with binary data (1s and 0s).

For convenience most databases provide string types and date types and sometimes a few others but you could store whatever you want in a database since the database is just a locker for your data.  Since the database doesn't know/care what an image is beyond a sequence of bytes it will store it and retrieve it as such and it is up to you to then interpret those bytes as an image.

Since the database doesn't understand complex binary types there is a catchall field type called BLOB (binary long object) in which you can store and retrieves binary data.

In pseudocode:

```
database.store(myImage.GetBytes());
```

then

```
Image myimage  = new Image (database.retrieve(...);
```

Notice the conversion to and from image to bytes is part of your code , not the databases.  The database only wants bytes for a BLOB field.